# NSUserDefaults with in-app Settings bundle

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm in the process of building an app and would prefer to have an in-app specific Settings bundle rather than make it available in the Settings application. I'm using NSUserDefaults class to save and retrieve them but would like to have the same Settings app look and feel. I wanted to use InAppSettingsKit or the llamasettings but don't know how to use them with NSUserDefaults class. I think those kits tell me how to create a .plist file and use their kits and no examples on NSUserDefaults. All I need is get the Settings app look and feel while at the same time use NSUserDefaults class to save and retrieve values.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The settings app is basically a grouped style UITableView. It is easy to recreate the look and fell by customising the cells of the UITableView by adding buttons and use NSUserDefaults to keep track of your settings.